# Errno 32 Broken Pipe when using easy.py in libsvm

Tags: python, mamp, libsvm, mamp-pro

a few days ago, I was still able to use the easy.py, but today, when I tried again, I got this error [errorno 32] broken pipe, which I haven't had it before. Everything is still the same, I did not change a single thing, recently I only updated java to version 8... That's all...

```
line = ''
while True:
    last_line = line
    line = f.readline()
    if not line: break
c,g,rate = map(float,last_line.split())
```

and this is the error:

```
Scaling training data...
Cross validation...
[Errno 32] Broken pipe
Try "grid.py" for more information.
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "easy.py", line 61, in <module>
    line = f.readline()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Have anybody had this error before?

P/S: I tried running it on two different machines, both using mac os 10.9.2, it can run normally on another machine and can't on the other one... The only differernt between them is one uses java and netbean 8, one uses java and netbean 7. On the machine that failed to run the program, I upgraded MAMP PRO in it to 3.03 yesterday.

Comment: What is the context of "f"? How was it opened?

Comment: This also happens to me both in Libsvm-3.16 and Libsvm-3.17

Comment: Please show us a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the contents of `easy.py`.

Comment: Please see the edit that i did in the question

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late, but did you ever fix this? I've had the same issue, and discovered it was a problem with `gnuplot`. It wasn't executing properly and once fixed it all went back to normal. It could be that the `Java` update meant that you also needed to update `gnuplot`.